# como elimino el ultimo caracter de una impresion realizada por FOR en java?

Tags: java, string, loops

Tengo:

```
for(i=0; i<vector.length; i++)
{
  System.out.print(Integer.toString(vector[i]) + " < ");
}
```

Ejemplo: La salida seria

> 1 < 2 < 3 < 4 <

Este ultimo signo quisiera eliminar de la impresion, intente con substring pero al estar en un `FOR`, no se puede. Me pueden ayudar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es, imprimir algo distinto en la última iteración de tu bucle, ponle una condición como esta:

```
for(i=0; i<vector.length; i++)
{
  if(i==vector.length-1)
      System.out.print(Integer.toString(vector[i]));
  else
      System.out.print(Integer.toString(vector[i]) + " < ");
}
```

También tienes la posibilidad de imprimir todos los casos menos el último y después, una vez que has salido del bucle, imprimir la última posición.

```
for(i=0; i<vector.length-1; i++)
{
   System.out.print(Integer.toString(vector[i]) + " < ");
}

System.out.print(Integer.toString(vector[vector.length-1]));
```

He intentado tocar el código lo menos posible y hacerlo entendible.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, la primera opción resulto la segunda no.

Comment: Repito muchisimas Gracias

Comment: perfecto!, mirare la segunda y si veo lo que pasa la edito. ánimo programando

Answer (score 3):

Una manera sencilla de hacer el ajuste es moviendo la escritura del `" < "` en una sentencia separada, y agregando una condición de forma que solo se escriba en todas las iteraciones salvo la primera:

```
for(i=0; i<vector.length; i++)
{
    if (i != 0) System.out.print(" < ");
    System.out.print(Integer.toString(vector[i]));
}
```

Otra manera es usando [`String.join`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.Iterable-), disponible a partir de Java 8. Asumo que `vector` es un arreglo de `int`. Tristemente, en ese caso, la sintaxis no queda tan compacta como uno quisiera, pero aquí va:

```
System.out.println(
    String.join(" < ", (Iterable<String>)Arrays.stream(vector)
                       .mapToObj(Integer::toString)::iterator));
```

Comment: Si no me equivoco, en tu primer ejemplo no haría lo que el OP pregunta, eliminas el signo "<" al principio pero hay que eliminarlo al final.

Comment: @Pablo si todos respetaran la consigna al pie de la letra, no habría buenas respuestas como esta (la única que en vez de quedarse con el problema, muestra una solución eficiente con `.join()`)... El objetivo está claro en la pregunta: agregar `" < "` en el medio de cada elemento. La forma en que el autor pregunta es como se le ocurre según su entendimiento.

Comment: No estoy de acuerdo, el usuario (por norma general) sabe lo que pregunta y aquí está bastante clara la pregunta: "Este ultimo signo quisiera eliminar de la impresion, intente con substring pero al estar en un FOR, no se puede. Me pueden ayudar". Además eso de decir que tu respuesta es la única que vale... veo varias que son correctas también. Un saludo

Comment: la primera opción de 'sstan' es correcta y funciona la segun.

Comment: la segunda no logre hacer que ande. Gracias sstan

Comment: la segunda funciono de maravilla, no me di cuenta que había dejado el FOR. Gracias